# Performing Flux Balance Analysis (FBA) or Metabolic Flux Analysis (MFA) on tracer metabolomic data

Tags: metabolism, computational-model, systems-biology

I have targeted tracer metabolomic data of a mammalian cell culture in 3 biological replicates, and 3 time-points (0, 10 and 60 minutes). Cultures were fed with <sup>13</sup>C6-glucose. After manual curation I have reliable isotopologue measures for 7 metabolites in glycolysis, 5 metabolites in the tricarboxylic acid cycle and 7 aminoacids. Is my dataset suitable for performing <sup>13</sup>C-MFA or FBA?

The metabolites in question:

- Hexose
- Hexose-P
- Hexose-BP
- 3PG
- DHAP
- PEP
- Pyruvate
- Citrate
- cis-Aconitate
- Oxoglutarate
- Malate
- Fumarate
- Glutamate
- Glutamine
- Aspartate
- Asparagine
- Arginine
- Serine
- Glycine

Comment: It would help to include which metabolites you have.

Comment: Thank you @David and Michael_A for your remarks and corrections. Here the metabolites I have : Hexose, Hexose-P, Hexose-BP,  3PG, DHAP, PEP,  Pyruvate;  Citrate, cis-Aconitate,   Oxoglutarate, Malate, Fumarate;  Glutamate, Glutamine, Aspartate, Asparagine, Arginine, Serine, Glycine.

Comment: The data are probably sufficient for _something_, but it's hard to evaluate without more details. What exactly are you trying to learn from this experiment?

Comment: thank you @MaximilianPress, indeed we would like to estimate metabolic fluxes in a similar manner as these researchers : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332843369_Core_Metabolism_Shifts_during_Growth_on_Methanol_versus_Methane_in_the_Methanotroph_Methylomicrobium_buryatense_5GB1  . But we have mammalian tissue instead.  I have some knowledge of python, but I have never used cobrapy

Comment: I believe no one can answer your question entirely, except you set up a model in question. You need some metabolic network based on which you would formulate, for further computations, your balance equations (flux equations). If those equations with their boundary selected well, you may have a network where you could compute then with your observations (known fluxes) the unknown fluxes.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have found this library https://masspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/education/sb2/chapters/sb2_chapter10.html which hopefully will help me to build the model as you suggested me. However, I guess I have to create myself a new stoichiometric matrix with my few metabolites, and therefore model the glycolisys+tca cicle with some "spureous" reactions that will be short-cuts when necessary (for example, oxoglutarate --> Fumarate)